# Python: Store a two-item list as a value in a dictionary from user input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simple grocery helper program that takes as inputs

a) an ingredient
b) a numerical value
c) a measurement (e.g. TB, cups)

and which will ultimately return a list of items needed.

Since I want to allow the user to input the same ingredient twice and then add the measurement to the ingredient previously entered, I'm trying to figure out how to store the user's numerical value and measurement inputs in the form of a two-item list as the dictionary's value so they can be modified later and then all nicely printed out.

Here's my crude attempt to get the main bit working:

```
ingredients = {}

program_run = True

while program_run:
  ingredient = input("Give me an ingredient: ")
  measurement = input("Unit of measurement? ")
  howMuch = input("How much? ")

  ingredients[ingredient] = howMuch

print(ingredients)
```

So how can I get user inputs `measurement` and `howMuch` to be stored in the form of a two-item list as the value of dictionary 'ingredients' so I end up with something like:

```
{"coriander": [2, "tsp"], "basil": [.5, "cups"]}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just define it as a list. `ingredients[ingredient] = [howMuch, measurement]`

Comment: Also, `input` will return a string by default so you probably want `ingredients[ingredient] = [float(howMuch), measurement]` assuming this is Python 3.

Comment: @roganjosh I agree though the OP will need to do a `try` `except` statement so they don't crash the app.

Comment: @roganjosh good observation about casting.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a list out of the `measurement` and `howMuch` variable then save that to the ingredients dict.

```
ingredients = {}

program_run = True

while program_run:
  ingredient = input("Give me an ingredient: ")
  measurement = input("Unit of measurement? ")
  howMuch = input("How much? ")

  ingredients[ingredient] = [howMuch, measurement]

print(ingredients)
```

If you want to format it better you could do it like this.

```
ingredients = {}

program_run = True

while program_run:
  ingredient = input("Give me an ingredient: ")
  symbol = input("Unit of measurement? ")
  measurement = input("How much? ")

  ingredients[ingredient] = [measurement, symbol]

print(ingredients)
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing my fat finger there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `ingredients[ingredient]` represents the value of the key `ingredient` in the dictionary `ingredients`. You want that the value is a list, hence you can do something like this:

```
ingredients = {}

program_run = True

while program_run:
      ingredient = input("Give me an ingredient: ")
      measurement = input("Unit of measurement? ")
      howMuch = input("How much? ")

      # cast measurement to float and create a list from user inputs
      details = [float(measurement), howMuch]

      # add the list to the dict
      ingredients[ingredient] = details
```